# Combining different elements of array in Numpy while doing vector operations

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a function `f` which I am using to evolve a Numpy array `z` repeatedly. Thus my code looks like this:

```
for t in range(100):
    z = f(z)
```

However, now I want to combine elements of array while evolving. For example, in simple Python, I would like to do something like this:

```
N = len(z)
for t in range(100):
    for i in range(len(z)):
         z_new[i] = f(z[i]) + z[(i-1)%N] + z[(i+1)%N]
    z = z_new
```

How can achieve the same thing in Numpy vector operations so that I wouldn't have to compromise with the great speed that Numpy gives me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: When ```i``` is the index of the last element, what will ```z[i+1]``` be?

Comment: I actually use modulo. So the actual entries are `z[(i-1)%N]` and `z[(i+1)%N]` so that `z[i+1] = z[0]` when `i` is last element. Also, here `N = len(z)`.

Comment: Slices are the fastest way to index your array, eg `z[1:]-z[:-1]`.  If you have to wrap around you will have to use slower advanced indexing or concatenation.  Look at the internals of `roll`. Look also at `take` and `put`.

Comment: Add the wrapping reqirement to your iterative example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can roll the data *back and forth* to achieve the same result.

```
Z = f(z)
Z = np.roll(Z, 1) + z
Z = np.roll(Z, -2) + z
z = np.roll(Z, 1)
```

---

I had also first thought about slicing but went with `np.roll` when I found it.

Prompted by @hpaulj's comment I came up with a slice solution:

```
q = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
Q = f(q)
# operate on the middle
Q[1:] += q[:-1]
Q[:-1] += q[1:]
# operate on the ends
Q[0] += q[-1]
Q[-1] += q[0]

q = Q.copy()
```

Comment: Actually my real task is much more complicated but I think this wonderful roll function should do the job. Thanks